# How to add keymapping for LSP code formatting in visual mode?

Tags: neovim, lsp, lua

In neovim I would like to set a keybinding -- via `lua` config -- to use LSP to format the visual selection when I type `\qf`.

Using this setting, I can format the *whole buffer* from normal mode:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '\\qf', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()<CR>', {noremap = true})
```

In order to format *just the visual selection*, I believe I need to use the `range_formatting()` function. I tried this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', '\\qf', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting()<CR>', {noremap = true})
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following error:

```lua
r_language_server: -3
2603: Error: argument is of length zero
Call: if (!nzchar(line)) return(units) 
Stack trace:
1: code_point_from_unit(text,position$character)
2: document$from_lsp_position(params$range$start)
3: dispatch(self, id, params)
```

How can I modify the keymap setting above to pass the start and end position of the selection, and format the visual selection using LSP?

Comment: The doc [`:h vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting%28%29) seems to say that you need to provide 3 arguments to the function: Some [formatting options](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-17/#formattingOptions) as well as the range to format. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I am a total beginner, so I don’t know how to pass the start and end positions as arguments to a lua function, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the `range_formatting()` states:

```
                                              *vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting()*
range_formatting({options}, {start_pos}, {end_pos})
                Formats a given range.

                Parameters: ~
                    {options}    Table with valid `FormattingOptions` entries.
                    {start_pos}  ({number, number}, optional) mark-indexed
                                 position. Defaults to the start of the last
                                 visual selection.
                    {end_pos}    ({number, number}, optional) mark-indexed
                                 position. Defaults to the end of the last
                                 visual selection.
```

Note that the default values are the *last* visual selection. A simple keybinding is thus:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', '\\qf', '<ESC><cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting()<CR>', {noremap = true})
```

Comment: why the initial `<ESC>` is needed in the key mapping? How did you figured it out? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I found this question while solving the same problem, but now the function `range_formatting()` is deprecated. Now should use `vim.lsp.formatexpr()` or `vim.lsp.buf.format()` instead.

You can define a function that does the same like:

```lua
function FormatFunction()
  vim.lsp.buf.format({
    async = true,
    range = {
      ["start"] = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, "<"),
      ["end"] = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, ">"),
    }
  })
end
```

And map this function the same way:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("v", "\\qf", "<Esc><cmd>lua FormatFunction()<CR>", {noremap = true})
```

Edit:

I tried to keep the answer simple and short, but maybe that is not the right way. As [wardw mentioned](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41441/46780), it's a better way to use `vim.keymap.set`, you can use it for both normal and visual mode. I personally add `async` option:

```lua
map({"n", "v"}, "\\gf", function()
    vim.lsp.buf.format({ async = true })
end, opts)
```

But be aware of editing buffer while formatting, as the documentation say:

> async boolean|nil If true the method won't block.
> Defaults to false. Editing the buffer while formatting
> asynchronous can lead to unexpected changes.

The difference between the function `FormatFunction` and `vim.lsp.buf.format` is that u cannot use `vim.lsp.buf.format` as cmd like

```
:lua vim.lsp.buf.format()
```

This will format the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

It's sufficient just to do

```
vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader>qf", vim.lsp.buf.format, { remap = false })
```

From [:h vim.lsp.buf.format()](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#vim.lsp.buf.format()),

> `range (table|nil)` Range to format. Table must contain start and end keys with {row, col} tuples using (1,0) indexing. Defaults to current selection in visual mode Defaults to nil in other modes, formatting the full buffer.

so the range already defaults to the current selection in visual mode. Super!

Comment: Bonus: See [Range Formatting With a Motion](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/User-contributed-tips#range-formatting-with-a-motion) in the lspconfig wiki, which is pretty sweet.